# How to reference a dom element in ember route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I was working on an EmberJS application developing.
I defined a route and a template for it

And there is a little button, which id is `myBtn` in that template

I wonder how and when i can reference that button in my `route.js`

If there is no way,i think i may wrote a single component and wrap it in that route(template),course,element reference in component is clearly and easily

Hope there is a hint for me

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code with which you have tried

Comment: If you must, you could always grab it with `document.querySelector`. But wanting to do that is probably an indication that something is not quite right with how you've organized things.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases there is no need for you to reference dom element (your button) in the route, your button and route should be loosely coupled it is how ember encourages building apps. Instead you should use `actions/events` to control your app or wrap it in `component` if you really need reference to dom.

Comment: thanks Bek.
if i want use jquryUI,as i click that button,i popup a jquryUI dialag,how to do?

Comment: have you looked at http://www.emberaddons.com maybe there is already addon for your usecase ? but generally if you want to use jquery UI related thing it is better to create component where you will have access to dom element of that component  like `this.$()` or `this.element`

Comment: thanks,i think maybe it is the only way before new version ember coming

Comment: think so, I think it will be possible when this will come along https://github.com/ef4/rfcs/blob/routeable-components/active/0000-routeable-components.md